# Implementing a download with SaveAs dialog box in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to show a PopUp to Save a file and the user has to choose the destination and change file type if he actually needs. I read many articles still not getting clear idea of what to do since I am new to .Net.
   This is the code.When I run the code and click link buttons in grid view the file will be downloaded without popup and without even asking User's permission where the downloaded files must be saved

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.CommandName == "Download")
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition","attachment; filename=" + e.CommandArgument);
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/") + e.CommandArgument);
            Response.End();

        }

    }
```

I need the following to be achieved.

- Display a SaveAs File dialog Box
- The type of file should automatically be displayed in SaveAs dialog box.Eg if the type of file is image then in SaveAs dialog box .jpg should be automatically displayed. 
  I have attached image of my output here
  [image]
  I am not really clear with this concept.Please help Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `SaveFileDialog` is a windows forms control, it doesn't work on a website.

A browser will display the "What do you want to do with this file" dialog whenever a server sends it a stream it can't handle by default - unfortunately, most browsers can handle text streams, so will just display them to the user.

But something like this should get you going:

```
// Clear the response buffer:
   Response.Clear();

   // Set the output to plain text:
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

   // Send the contents of the textbox to the output stream:
   Response.Write(txtNewFile.Text);

   // End the response so we don't get anything else sent (page furniture etc):
   Response.End();
```

Comment: I have attached my output page.Still I am not getting any popup @Rajeev Mehta

Answer (score 0):

To save you all (as well as my future self) the trouble of searching all over the place just to find terrible answers on almost every form post out there. Here is a small `ASP.NET/C#` code snippet that will prompt the user with the save/open dialog box to download a file.

```
String FileName = "FileName.txt";
String FilePath = "C:/...."; //Replace this
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "text/plain";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");
response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

For more content types check

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#List_of_common_media_types